# When there are some words between 'a' and the corresponding noun, do I use 'an'?

Tags: articles

Which sentence is correct?

> I performed **a** reliability analysis.

or

> I performed **an** reliability analysis.

Comment: See [***Purdue OWL: How to Use Articles (a/an/the)***](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct:

> I performed a reliability analysis.

The choice between **a** and **an** has nothing to do with the noun. It is entirely dependent on the sound that comes after the indefinite article.

> a whole hour.
>
> a tropical island.
>
> an honourable solider.

If the next word after the indefinite article starts with a consonant sound, the indefinite article needs to be **a**.

If the next word after the indefinite article starts with a vowel sound, the indefinite article needs to be **an**.

Comment: I just wanted to reiterate that it's based on whether or not the word begins with a vowel *sound*, not an actual vowel, as the last example in this answer demonstrates. I've seen this trip people up before, even native speakers.

Comment: @NathanK In some cases you'll see people choose what looks like the wrong one of a/an because an initial consonant is silent in *their* dialect but not yours, or vice versa.  (I can't think of an example right now.)

Comment: @zwol, something I see a lot in electronics is different a/an use depending on how people speak acronyms. I prefer to say SPI as "es-pea-eye", so I use "an" before it, other people say it as "spy", so they don't. There are probably other examples with acronyms.

Comment: @Austin: There sure are, the one that comes most readily to my mind is "LED". A led or an L E D.

Comment: @zwol I wasn't really referring to differences in dialect or acronyms (or they get it wrong for their own dialect). "Herb" is a good example. In BrE the 'h' is usually pronounced while it's usually silent in AmE.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not use use "an" depends on **the word that directly follows the article.**

If the initial sound of that word is a vowel sound, we use "an." Otherwise, we use "a."

For your sentence, it would be

> I performed **a** reliability test.

because "reliability" does not start with a vowel sound.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use a or an entirely depends on the word directly after the a/an.

> An analysis
>
> A reliability analysis
>
> An accurate reliability analysis

etc.